# How do I format my pandas dataframe through python to get columns in the csv output?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing code such that I get hours of operation of a restaurant:

## This is my input code:

```
merge_HOO = my_list  
merge_HOO=pd.DataFrame([(merge_HOO)],
columns = ['day','start','end']) 
print(merge_HOO)
merge_HOO.to_csv('merge_HOO_test1.csv')
```

OUTPUT:

```
    hours_type  is_open_now open
0   REGULAR FALSE   [{'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}]
```

However, I want the output to look like in Column 1: header should be `'day'`, column 2: `'start'`, column 3: `'end'` and under each column should be the respective values.

## I also got this error when I ran the code:

```
con=len(content)))
```

> AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

Edit: Added what my_list looks like.

```
my_list = [{'open': [{'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}], 'hours_type': 'REGULAR',
  'is_open_now': False}]

for i in my_list[0]["open"]:
    del i["is_overnight"]

print(my_list)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: can you please add a couple of element of `my_list`?

Comment: Yes I have edited it and mentioned the same @VincenzoLavorini

Answer (score 0):

You have adapt the structure of `merge_HOO` to a dict whose keys contain the data for your columns. Since I suppose you will have more than one restaurant in the end, I added a counter `item` for each restaurant in `my_list`

```
my_list = [{'open': [{'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0},
                     {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1},
                     {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2},
                     {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3},
                     {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4},
                     {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5},
                     {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}], 'hours_type': 'REGULAR',
            'is_open_now': False}]

merge_HOO = {'item': [], 'day': [], 'start': [], 'end': []}
for i, restaurant in enumerate(my_list):
    for item in restaurant['open']:
        merge_HOO['item'].append(i)
        merge_HOO['day'].append(item['day'])
        merge_HOO['start'].append(item['start'])
        merge_HOO['end'].append(item['end'])

merge_HOO = pd.DataFrame(merge_HOO,
                         columns=['item', 'day', 'start', 'end'])
print(merge_HOO)
```

It will yield

```
   item  day start   end
0     0    0  1100  2200
1     0    1  1100  2200
2     0    2  1100  2200
3     0    3  1100  2200
4     0    4  1100  2200
5     0    5  1100  2200
6     0    6  1100  2100
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. God bless you @ascripter

Comment: Then I'd be thankful if you also [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer :)

Comment: is there anyway to make it in a wide format, since this output is a long data format?

Comment: by wide format i mean having day,start,end all in a single column and values kept in rows next to them like day 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 and similarly for other like start 1100 2200 1100 2200....

Comment: I am not sure what you mean (and what you finally intend to to with the data). You want the entry of each cell to be a list? Then you'll end up with strings of lists in the csv. Are you sure you have a well defined problem?

Comment: day 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
start 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100
end 2200 2200 2200 2200 2200 2200 2100
This is how I want my output to look in csv

Comment: day   0  1  2  3              4        5              6
    start    1100     1100      1100     1100   1100 1100 1100
    end   2200 2200 2200 2200  2200 2200 2100

Comment: Why are you using pandas? Have a look into the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. It seems like that's what you actually need.

Comment: Did my answer help you finally in some way? If so, I'd be thankful if you'd [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.